# .clearcontent not working on just one spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I have the strangest problem. Just one function seems not to be working on my Spreadsheet. I can setContent in a cell but I cannot clear it.

```
function buildCrawlGrid(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dynadotS = ss.getSheetByName('Dynadot');
  dynadotS.getRange('b5').clearContent;
}
```

I am very familiar with the use of this function and never had an issue in the past. I have tried in a different sheet in the same spreadsheet and have the same issue. It's not that the spreadsheet object is misnamed because I was able to set content in the cell. I tried SpreadsheetApp.flush() to ensure it wasn't latency. Any ideas what might cause this apart from a corrupt spreadsheet?

Comment: When you modified `dynadotS.getRange('b5').clearContent;` to `dynadotS.getRange('b5').clearContent();`, what result will you obtain? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearcontent) Please add `()` and test it again.

Comment: Well spotted Tanaike. It seems the reason  never saw this error before is that the new editor for apps script autofills the clearContent without brackets whilst the old one inserted brackets as they should be!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a bit late...but maybe could be useful for someone reading this.
Try to change with () at the end

```
dynadotS.getRange('b5').clearContent();
```